# Response from HttpURLConnection different from curl response

Tags: java, curl, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I am trying to get response from HttpURLConnection but it throws java.io.FileNotFoundException.

HttpURLConnection :

```
/**
* Call URL using HttpURLConnection
*
* @param url - the URL to be called
**/
public static String getHUCResponse(String url) throws IOException {

    InputStream inps = null;
    String res = "";
    try {

        URL getURL = new URL(url);

        HttpURLConnection huc =  ( HttpURLConnection )  getURL.openConnection ();
        huc.setConnectTimeout(60000); // 1 minute
        huc.setReadTimeout(60000); // 1 minute

        huc.setRequestMethod("GET");

        inps = huc.getInputStream(); // throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
        res = IOUtils.toString(inps,"UTF8");
    } 
    catch (IOException except){
        throw except;
    }       
    finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(inps);
    }

    return res;
}
```

Error trace:

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: url
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1401)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
        at HttpUtils.getHUCResponse(HttpUtils.java:440)
```

curl:

```
    $ curl url
    user not found

    $ curl -I url
    HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
    Server: nginx/1.4.2
    Date: Sat, 26 Oct 2013 23:45:20 GMT
    Content-Length: 14
    Connection: keep-alive
```

I expected to get "user not found" as response from HttpURLConnection since this is what is being returned with 404 error.

What could I be missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When the error code is 400 or higher you will get the input stream of the response with `getErrorStream` rather than `getInputStream` (yes, I know, someone thought this would be a good idea somehow).

When you call getInputStream but the code is 400 or higher then I think I remember getting null in that case but it seems to be getting you a FileNotFoundException, you just need to add a check for the getResponseCode() and use the right method to get the stream.

Comment: I have added error trace. Calling getErrorStream would mean adding a check on response code. Is there a way in Java one can get a response returned by curl whichever the return code? IOUtils is from a different apache package but it's not cause of issue.

Comment: it may be since you are telling it to handle an inputstream which is in fact null... curl is a command line tool, it has nothing to do with what you are doing in java.
There's many libraries you can use in java, this is about HttpURLConnection, in which case no, the response will be either in getErrorStream or getInputStream depending on the status code and if there is actually a body in the response.

Comment: The error doesn't come from IOUtils. It's thrown even if I remove the line on IOUtils. But you're right on getErrorStream. I probably need to use something different from HttpURLConnection (that would behave in similar fashion as curl).

Answer (score 0):

Am, Java is doing things righ. 404 http code equals to `FileNotFoundException`. `user not found` is strange error message which you will never see from `HttpURLConnection`